# sharepoint field createdby matches which property of AD

Tags: sharepoint-2007

As a requirement im using sharepoint object model and trying to compare **"Created By"** field of a List Item with the Current User Logged on.

My Question is  :

**If the Same user who has created the item logged on**

Does  **Web.CurrentUser.LoginName = Created By Matches??** or anyother active directory property that matches with Created By

Please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge,  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` should match the `CreatedBy` property.